# TYPO3 - Translations set but neither processed nor displayed

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I've been building a TYPO3 website. I wanted to use the multi-language capacity of TYPO3 and get acquainted with the CMS. I'm using V.9.5.6 at the moment with the Introduction Package.

I followed the manual on multi-language setup here : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-frontendlocalization/9.5/en-us/Index.html

When switching languages, the page refreshes but no visible changes occur.

---

I deleted the original "German" et "Dansk" languages, then added "French" and "German". I used the contact page as proving grounds.

I added translations in germand and french from the original english page I built. There's only a header and a contact form. In english, it reads "contact form". In german and french it should read respectively "Kontaktieren Sie uns" and "Contactez-nous".

The languages UIDs are 2 for German and 3 for French. The template, in the languages section, has "auto" for the list of languages and it pulls correctly the 2 I added, in the correct order.

---

In a properly setup website, if default language is English, and I click on the "German" or "French" language button at the bottom, the page should refresh and display the content translated in the language I selected and have the selected language in bold at the bottom of the page.

When clicking on the bottom links, it adds the correct L= parameter and the page loads but no visible change occur on the page. Even the language link at the bottom of the page has "Default" in bold instead of whatever I clicked.

There is NO error message when clicking on the language buttons.

---

I'm pretty sure this is not the standard behavior of a TYPO3 multi-lingual installation. What can cause the CMS to not fetch a translated content OR fail to get the language change information from the parameters passed in the URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer this vague question.

Usually there are three pitfalls you should look at:

1. realurl (or routes in v9) here is a nice gist: https://gist.github.com/koehlersimon/9dcbabb6b1b2adcbc84db96fd144fb08
2. TypoScript settings for the languages: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-frontendlocalization/9.5/en-us/TyposcriptConfiguration/Index.html#typoscript-configuration
3. proper .htaccess in connection with [1.]

I also suggest to update to v 9.5.9
There have been plenty bugfixes since v 9.5.6 and updating within branch 9.5.X is really easy and non-breaking!

Comment: Thank you very much, issue solved. Details to follow :

[1.] : The YAML configuration was not processed correctly and I did the changes manually using the backend editor of Site Configuration. Once it was done, the pages changed to 404 except the homepage
[2.]  : did not help as languages were set as detailled above, not using TScript
[3.]  : I changed the .htaccess to a pure directly from the source

After some adjusting in the YAML (domain name, etc...), I got 404'd again. Adjusting protocol (http to https) in site config' solved it (since i force https redirect).
Thank you again ! :)